# Problems with solr docker suggester in context query: blanks are not correctly processed

Tags: solr

I am using Solr version 8.8.1 in a docker container. I use an address query system based on a csv file. I want to get a city in relation to the street name. The fields in my managed-schema are looking like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="sugAddress" type="text_suggest" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="sugCity" type="text_suggest"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <copyField source="CITY" dest="sugAddress"/>
 <copyField source="POSTCODE" dest="sugAddress"/>
 <copyField source="STREET" dest="sugAddress"/>
 <copyField source="CITY" dest="sugCity"/>
```

My solrconfig.xml is looking like this:

```
<searchComponent name="solr_suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">sugCitySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
   <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str> 
    <str name="field">sugCity</str>
    <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
    <str name="weightField">sugAddress</str> 
    <str name="contextField">sugAddress</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggest</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>solr_suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

The result of normal query (without suggester) looks like this:

```
{
 "sugAddress":["Am Bahndamm",
          "3",
          "3",
          "65432",
          "Testcity"],
        "sugStreet":"Am Bahndamm",
        "sugPostcode":"65432",
        "sugCity":"Testcity",
        "id":"1e470f44-fe3a-4fb9-b71d-ca556a48c55f",
        "_version_":1695636026132791297,
        "NO_FROM":[3],
        "NO_TO":[3],
        "POSTCODE":[65432]
},
{
 "sugAddress":["Teststreet",
          "4",
          "4",
          "65432",
          "Testcity"],
        "sugStreet":"Teststreet",
        "sugPostcode":"65432",
        "sugCity":"Testcity",
        "id":"1e470f44-fe3a-4fb9-b71d-ca556a48c55f",
        "_version_":1695636026132791297,
        "NO_FROM":[4],
        "NO_TO":[4],
        "POSTCODE":[65432]
}
```

All indexes are build.

The following query brings correctly one result:
http://localhost:8983/solr/addrescore/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=sugCitySuggester&suggest.q=Test&suggest.cfq=Teststreet

But the following returns no results:
http://localhost:8983/solr/addrescore/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=sugCitySuggester&suggest.q=Test&suggest.cfq=Am%20Bahndamm

There seems to be a problem with spaces in the context query.
Has someone an idea?

Comment: Is there missprint?
 <copyField source="STREET" dest="sugAddress"/>
should be 
 <copyField source="STREET" dest="sugStreet"/>
?

Comment: from my understanding you need these 2 lines in your code: <field name="sugstreet" type="text_suggest"  indexed="true" stored="true"/> and <copyField source="STREET" dest="sugStreet"/> to achieve what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggester [works on terms](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/suggester.html). That is why, first of all, open Solr admin console and check terms for *sugStreet* field. According to your question, this information should be availably by this URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/addrescore/schema?field=sugStreet

I expect that "Am Bahnda" will not be on that list. Then your goal will be to define, why this street is not on the list of terms. I suspect that it can be because of how *sugStreet* field is configured. In order to have "Am Bahndamm" as one term, you need to make it untokenized(by default all Sitecore search fields are tokenized). Tokenized field means that your string is split by dividers(spaces, tabs, commas). I expect that "Am Bahndamm" was divided into 2 terms: "Am" and "Bahndamm". And "Am" was ignored due to length shorter than the 3 symbols.

You will need to change *sugStreet* field configuration and make it untokenized.

```
indexType="UNTOKENIZED"
```

Then rebuild indexes and check your terms on Solr admin console to make sure that it started to work.

UPDATE:
As far as I understand, you want to achieve it without touching Sitecore configuration.

I this case you need to define your `sugStreet` field with new type without tokenizer by spaces:

```
<field name="sugStreet" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Then you need to copy source field to destination:

```
<copyField source="STREET" dest="sugStreet"/>
```

Afterward, you need to rebuild the index. Copying of field value happens after analisis, so it should work. You should be able to get untokenized terms in `sugStreet` field and tokenized in `STREET` field.

Comment: I have tried this by adding this property to the field: <field name="sugStreet" type="text_suggest"  indexed="true" stored="true"  indexType="UNTOKENIZED"/> But when starting, i get the error message: Can't load schema /var/solr/data/saddresscore/conf/managed-schema: Invalid field property: indexType

Comment: @tho I mean to put this configuration to Sitecore config, not directly to the managed scheme. Then, after putting it to Sitecore configuration, you can populate the scheme from Sitecore https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/solr-managed-schemas.html

If for some reason you want to do it directly in Solr configuration then you need to make sure that your field sugStreet uses text_suggest field type. (or any other, but with solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory to make sure that your terms are not split by space)

Comment: We use solr in a docker environment, so there is no way to use Sitecore. We already use the solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory in the field for the suggester and the context. But the context query suggester.cfq seems to not accept blanks.

Comment: "We use solr in a docker environment, so there is no way to use Sitecore." - that is not true. Docker is only the way how you host your project. You still are able to change anything that you need.

Comment: @tho Did you check terms? (the first part of my answer, to figure out what is wrong)

Comment: Yes, it look like this:  /90 Top-Terms:  

    177
        am

    74
        walserstr

    72
        au
        erahorn

    65
        b

    64
        dmerstr

    46
        h

    33
        w
        ldelestr

    29
        fle

    27
        hagelholz

    24
        eschenbornrasen

    23
        bach
        biemker

    22
        schwarzwassertalstr

    21
        wildentalstr

    19
        frauenmarkt

    18
        bahndamm
        oberseitestr

Comment: @tho Ok. We know that terms are tokenized by space, but we don't need it. Could you update your question and include configuration for sugStreet field, please?
Alsow, I have updated my answer with suggestions how to achieve it only with modifying Solr configs, please try it.

Comment: The configuration of the sugStreet field is already  
<field name="sugStreet" type="text_suggest" indexed ="true"/> The copy directives are: <copyField source⁵="STREET" dest="sugAddress"/>              <copyField source="STREET" dest="sugStreet"/>  The field sugAddress is used for context search wichtig KeywordTokenizer: ....suggest.q=Düss&suggest.cfq =Königsallee delivers correctly "Düsseldorf" wheras ...suggest.q=Hamb&suggest.cfq=An der Alster delivers nothing.

Comment: The following works correctly for the street suggest: ...suggest.q=An der&suggest.cfq=Hamburg delivers "An der Alster". There seems to be a problem with spaces in the context search by suggest.cfq.